# How to count selected checkboxes in React Native in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

## Whole code is here

I render two flat list, One shows category name and other shows its sub categories with check box.
Now i want, when user checked multiple or one check box of the sub catogories, The count shows in category like
Health(count = 2) is category: if i checked pharmacy and hopital.
1 pharmacy
2 hospital
3 nurse

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
var { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
import {CheckBox} from 'native-base';

 const CategoriesList = ({item}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
   const [selected,setSelected] = useState([0]);

   function onChange( items) {
     if (checked==false) {
      setSelected([...selected, items]);
    }
    
    else {
     setSelected((prev) =>
        prev.filter((currItem) => currItem.category !== items.name)
       );
   }
   }
  

   const ToggleCheck = () => {
       setChecked(!checked)
   }
  



  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: "row",
        width: width,
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          fontWeight: "bold",
          color: "black",
          alignSelf: "center",
          flexGrow: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 10,
        }}
      >
        
        {item.name}
      
      
      
        
      
          <CheckBox color='#B50900' checked={checked} onPress={(checked)=>{onChange(checked),ToggleCheck()}} /> 

          <Text>{selected.length > 0 ? selected.length : null}  </Text>
 
                   
                             
      
        
      </Text>
      
    </View>
  )}

export default CategoriesList
```

**I want to achieve same logic in React Native, you can check by clicking on link**
*https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-co324?file=/index.js*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same react link that you have provided but using react native.

It may not seems to work on `codesandbox` because it uses react native web.
but it should work on react native app.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-paper-hcyfc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check Box count still increase by one, Even i unchecked or unselect check box. you have any solution for this

Comment: Coz this is on the web so `checked` is actually an `event`, but on mobile environment it will be a `boolean`

Comment: Checkout the documentation of Checkbox https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/checkbox/

Comment: Or use https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox if you don't want to install the entire `react-native-elements`

Comment: `const CategoriesList = ({item,onChangeTotal}) => {
    const [check, setChecked] = useState(false)
    const [selected,setSelected] = useState([0]);
    useEffect(() => {
      onChangeTotal({
        category: item.category,
        value: selected.length
      });
    }, [selected]);
    
    function onChange(checked, item) {
      
  
      if (checked) {
        
        setSelected([...selected, item]);
       
  
      }else {
        setSelected((prev) =>
          prev.filter((currItem) => currItem.value == item.value)
        );
      }
    }`

Comment: <CheckBox
          
           
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            name="vehicle1"
            checked={check}
            // onChange={()=>{ToggleCheck()}}
            onPress={(checked) =>{ToggleCheck(),onChange(checked, item)}}
            
  
          /> check box i already used from React ntaive element

Comment: still when i uncheck checkbox count increase.

Comment: Right, I fixed it you can check now
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-paper-hcyfc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But I encourage you to use https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox rather than react native elements checkbox, but I've used it because the first one doesn't support react native web